# How to use the result of an IF statement as a variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code as follows:

```js
function DetailFacture2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var DetailDEVIS = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('DetailDEVIS'));
  var FACTUREDevis = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('FACTUREDevis'));
  var DetailFactureDevis = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('DetailFactureDevis'));
  var lastrowpaste = FACTUREDevis.getLastRow();
  var numrow = FACTUREDevis.getRange(lastrowpaste,13).getValue()
  var lastrowpaste2 = DetailFactureDevis.getLastRow() - numrow +2;
  var data = DetailDEVIS.getDataRange().getValues();
  var DetailD = FACTUREDevis.getRange(lastrowpaste,2).getValue();
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][1] == DetailD){ //[1] because column B
      var firstrowcopy = i+1;
      Logger.log(firstrowcopy)
      return (firstrowcopy)
    }
  }
};
```

It does return the correct value, but how do you use "firstrowcopy" as a fixed var?
I would like to use as follows:

```js
function DetailFacture2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var DetailDEVIS = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('DetailDEVIS'));
  var FACTUREDevis = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('FACTUREDevis'));
  var DetailFactureDevis = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('DetailFactureDevis'));
  var lastrowpaste = FACTUREDevis.getLastRow();
  var numrow = FACTUREDevis.getRange(lastrowpaste,13).getValue()
  var lastrowpaste2 = DetailFactureDevis.getLastRow() - numrow +2;
  var data = DetailDEVIS.getDataRange().getValues();
  var DetailD = FACTUREDevis.getRange(lastrowpaste,2).getValue();
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][1] == DetailD){ //[1] because column B
      var firstrowcopy = i+1;
      var source = DetailDEVIS.getRange(firstrowcopy,1,numrow-1);
      var destination = DetailFactureDevis.getRange(lastrowpaste2,3);
      source.copyTo(destination);
    }
  }
};
```

But, as one would expect, it cannot work as it loops...

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is the loop supposed to do because right now it would keep copying over `DetailFactureDevis.getRange(lastrowpaste2,3)` because lastrowpast2 doesn't change

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  You need to go back to drawing board or use the debugger to single step through because your doing some nonsensical things.  You may have a reason for them but it's not obvious to me.  It's just looks like you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question too. The code doesn't look well. Here is just my guess. Try to change the last lines this way:

```
// ...

  var firstrowcopy = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i][1] == DetailD){ //[1] because column B
      firstrowcopy = i+1;
      break;
    }
  }

  var source = DetailDEVIS.getRange(firstrowcopy,1,numrow-1);
  var destination = DetailFactureDevis.getRange(lastrowpaste2,3);
  source.copyTo(destination);
}
```